# Rewrite with 404 urls with nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite some urls which are showing up as 404's but the I can't get the rewrite to work. The Urls look like this `/ossobuco-alla-milanese​​/1451114854360.1451114854360?time=1451114851111`. I would like to remove `1451114854360.1451114854360?time=1451114851111` with a rewrite.

In my nginx config I have the following rewrite rule

`rewrite "^\/(.*)\/(\d{13}\.\d{13}\?time=\d{13})$" /$1/ permanent;`

I tested the regex in 2 online regex tools [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aF2oF8/1) and [regex pal](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93773) and it should work but the don't seem to work on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end its was just a really simple location block and the ? removes the args.

```
location ~* ^/(.+)/\d+\.\d+$ {
    rewrite ^/(.+)/\d+\.\d+$ /$1? permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To match query string use `$args`:

```
location / {
    if ($args ~* "^time=\d+") {
        set $args '';
        rewrite "^/(.+)/\d+\.\d+/?$" /$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

PS: If you want to match only `13digits.13digits` then use:

```
rewrite "^/(.+)/\d{13}\.\d{13}/?$" /$1 permanent;
```

Comment: I tried this and it rewrites the url to https://domain.tld/ and not to https://domain.tld/ossobuco-alla-milanese​​/

Comment: Namaste anubhava! do you know about a site where we can talk? I want your advice on something,can you please help?.

Comment: Dhanyavaad Anubhava sir, I have never created a chat room on this site in my 3years. but i will try try and will let you know. THANKS ANUHBAVA sir jee , sorry for my poor hindi, I am so ager to learn it. I am learning it.

Comment: May I know why you unaccepted so long after answer was submitted? Your own answer doesn't ensure query string contains `time=`